# set fixed position for bootstrap search

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

i am using bootstrap search design for my table.. here is the problem that i am facing in image

[image]

when i scroll right to the window the search and the paging style also changes its position.. i want it to be fixed at the top right and bottom right of the table even if i scroll the table...

here is the bootstrap code for the search i am using..

```
  $('#dtreport').DataTable({
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sLengthMenu": 'Display <select name="dtAgents_length" aria-controls="dtAgents" class="form-control input-sm">' +
                                                    '<option value="5">5</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="10">10</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="25">25</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="50">50</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="75">75</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="100">100</option>' +
                                                    '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
                                                '</select> records',
                        "sInfo": '<label>Displaying _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records.</label>',
                        "sZeroRecords": '<center><span style="color: red;"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i>  No report found.</span></center>',
                        "sInfoEmpty": '<label>Displaying 0 to 0 of 0 records.</label>',
                        "sInfoFiltered": '<label>(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)</label>'
                    },
                    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 'All']],
                    "iDisplayLength": 5
                });
```

thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"scrollX": true,
                    columnDefs: [
                        {
                            targets: 0,
                            type: 'natural'
                        }
                    ],
```

just add these line after the datatable({..

it worked for me..